# Historical OFAC SDN lists

Tags: data-request, usa, government, finance

I am looking for historical versions of the OFAC's Specially Designated Nationals (SDN) list (more details about the list can be found [here](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Pages/default.aspx)).

The OFAC ([Office of Foreign Assets Control](https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/offices/Pages/Office-of-Foreign-Assets-Control.aspx)) regularly publishes updated revisions of the SDN list in various formats, but old lists are not available there.

I found some old versions of the list on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130101000000*/http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml), but the collection is far from complete (e.g. for 2013 there are only 7 out of 70 list revisions in the archive).

Does anyone know of a source for the historical lists (preferrably in XML format)?

Comment: I just wanted to check if you were able to find a solution to this Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Archive of Changes to the SDN and NS-ISA Lists](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Pages/archive.aspx) looks complete to me.

There's no XML. At a glance the ".txt" files seem formulaic. They might not be difficult to transform using a programming language.

If there is more information that you are seeking, it may be necessary to [submit a Freedom of Information Act request](http://www.foia.gov/report-makerequest.html) to the Office of Foreign Asset Control, which is among the Departmental Offices in the Department of the Treasury.

Comment: Note: using the text files it is difficult to update the historic information because the text files are missing the unique identifier which is present in the XML versions and the CSV versions